# Solve $I^{\prime}(a)=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{2 a-2 \cos x}{1-2 a \cos x+a^{2}} d x$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

I tried to compute  $I^{\prime}(a)=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{2 a-2 \cos x}{1-2 a \cos x+a^{2}} d x$

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
&\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{2 a-2 \cos x}{1-2 a \cos x+a^{2}} d x&\\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{2(a-1)+4 \sin ^{2} \frac{x}{2}}{(a-1)^{2}+4 a \cdot \sin ^{2} \frac{x}{2}} d x\\
&=2 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2(a-1)+4 \sin ^{2} x}{(a-1)^{2}+4 \operatorname{asin}^{2} x} d x\\
&=\frac{2}{a} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(1+\frac{2 a(a-1)-(a-1)^{2}}{(a-1)^{2}+4 a \sin ^{2} x}\right) d x\\
&=\frac{\pi}{a}+\frac{2}{a} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{a^{2}-1}{(a-1)^{2}+4 a \sin ^{2} x} d x\\
&=\frac{\pi}{a}+\frac{2}{a} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\frac{a+1}{a-1} \sec ^{2} x}{1+\left(\frac{a+1}{a-1}\right)^{2} \tan ^{2} x} d x\\
&=\frac{\pi}{a}+\frac{2}{a} \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{1+u^{2}}d u\\
&=\frac{2 \pi}{a}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

But I can't find my mistake.

Comment: What is the correct answer?

Comment: How do you know there's a mistake, Yiyuan?

Comment: Ah, if $a=1$ then the integrand reduces to $1$ so the answer is $\pi$, but Yiyuan's formula gives $2\pi$, so I guess there must be a mistake.

Comment: Yes, I found the error in the same way,Gerry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result $I=2\pi/a$ is true only if $a>1$, for a<1 $I=0$.
When $a<1$, $t=\frac{a+1}{a-1} \tan x \implies t=0 (x=0) ~\text{but}~ t=-\infty (x=\pi/2)$. Then
$$I=\left(1+\frac{|a-1|}{a-1}\right)\frac{\pi}{a}$$
When $a=1$ the orininal integral is $\pi$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I know what went wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well,your mistake is in the last step, I am assuming that you made the substitution $\frac{a+1 }{a-1}\tan x=u$ and when $-1<a<1$ the limits would be $-\infty$ and $0$.

And your integral would vanish.

Comment: I get it, thanks.